# Does github expose an API for linguist?

Tags: github-api, github-linguist

I looked through the github API docs and couldn't find an answer.

Does github expose [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) information via any API endpoints?

I'm looking to get languages associated with a repo, as detected by linguist.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub exposes the language breakdown as computed by Linguist via the API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/languages
----
{
  "C": 78769,
  "Python": 7769
}
```